# How to find the percentage in my python list

Tags: python, list

So i am doing an assignment, i need to find the percentage of occupied spaces in a car park, i have got my list and the calulation for pencentage. when i run the program i get 0%.

I assume i am doing something wrong as the list is not being picked up.

Just looking for some hints and tips not a full on answer :)

```
#Find the percentage of occupied car spaces.

#Input: Cars in spaces
occupied_spaces = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0] 

#Output: of spaces occupied
spaces = 0
cars = 1


#calualtion to find percentage
percentage = (spaces/(cars)*100)

print (percentage,'% of spaces are occupied')
```

Comment: So `1` means that the space is occupied, right?

Comment: yes, sorry i didn't explain that very well

Answer (score 1):

This one line to calculate percentage occupied should be enough:

```
percentage = (sum(occupied_spaces)/len(occupied_spaces)) * 100
```

Since, you told you cannot use the sum function, you can do it in one line like so:

```
percentage = (occupied_spaces.count(1)/len(occupied_spaces)) * 100
```

Comment: thank you, i just browsed my work, they dont want us to use the sum function. I didn't explain very well. sorry. But thank you :)

Comment: No problem! Were you able to solve it or still stuck on it?

Comment: Still stuck atm, i know i need to have (len) in there so it can count the list, but i cant figure out how to get it work

Comment: I have updated the answer with another solution. Please check if this meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate occupied spaces like so:

```
occupied_spaces = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0] 
cars = occupied_spaces.count(1)
spaces = occupied_spaces.count(0)  # this variable is not used, so you can safely remove it
percentage = cars/len(occupied_spaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the Python **statistics** module:

```
from statistics import mean 
print(mean(occupied_spaces)*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your code, you have two variables named `spaces` and `cars`, each of them given the values of `0` and `1` respectively. When you try to find the percentage  of occupied spaces in your list, you divide `spaces` which is `0` with `cars`. This will always give you `0` as a result because you're not getting the actual number of cars in your list. To do that, you could do:

```
percentage = (occupied_spaces.count(1) / len(occupied_spaces)) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply count the number o 1's in the `occupied_spaces` list. Then divide the count number by the length of the `occupied_spaces` list and multiply with `100`. 
for getting length of `occupied_spaces` use `len(occupied_spaces)`